# SSH errors with Jenkins git plugin

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

There are lots of question on here about `Permission denied (publickey)` errors when using the [Jenkins git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).

Can someone explain the authentication flow this plugin uses to check out a repository? I can't find a good description on the plugin page.

I want to just SSH into the build slave, checkout the repository there, then run my job, but clearly that is not how it works.

I guess I could add my credentials to the jenkins master, but I dont want any code there. I want it on my build slave.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has nothing to do with git really. As their documentation states, it relies on git runtime which in its turn relies on system environment when it comes to secure connections. Ssh requires client to have valid key to connect and fails to that message if client does not provide one. Without any additional actions, key is not injected into environment, so client could not provide any valid key.

What you actually can use is [ssh agent plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin). That allows to add key to ssh-agent on slave that will be catched up by git.